# Pyphantomjs makes python crash

Tags: python, crash, pyqt

I'm just trying to open a web page with [pyphantomjs](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs/wiki/Api_reference), but it makes python crash. I don't know if there is a problem or if I am just using it wrong, as the documentation is one of the crappiest I've seen...

My code:

```
from pyphantomjs import webpage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wp = webpage.WebPage()
    wp.open("www.google.com")
    print wp.content()
```

[My crash report.](http://pastebin.com/AcQQLYj1)

I'm running python 2.7 on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Is that the right way to use that lib? Why not try in the command line first instead of eclipse?

Comment: I have no idea, the documentation is not very complete... I tried the command line, but it is not possible to do what I want (open a URL), it is just possible to run a local JS script with the command line.

Comment: Okay, then question is what would like to achieve? Can it be done via urllib2? or mechanize?

Comment: I'm trying to get a web page after the javascript OnLoad has been executed, so I need a JS friendly browser in Python. So I'm pretty sure this can't be done with urllib2. I don't know about mechanize, but I went with building my own browser in PyQt without showing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do a Google search for "PhantomJS API reference" or "PyPhantomJS API reference"? Both search terms yield good results as the first link. I don't know how you can say the documentation is bad, as it's all over the place if you simply look for it.

If you had read the project description[1](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs/wiki/Api_reference), you would know that it's scripted using JS, not Python (while theoretically possible, it's a little hard to do, and I haven't tried before). The program comes with an examples directory when you download it, how could you have missed that? Check the examples (can be downloaded from the [downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/downloads/list), and also provided with the zip file download!) on how to use the program.

You can find more information in the PyPhantomJS [API Reference](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs/wiki/Api_reference).

Project Pages: [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) | [PyPhantomJS](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs/)

An example script for you:

```
var page = new WebPage();
page.open('http://www.google.com/', function(status) {
    // do something
    phantom.exit();
});
```

[1](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs/wiki/Api_reference) PyPhantomJS is a minimalistic, headless, WebKit-based, **JavaScript-driven tool**...

python pyphantomjs.py [options] **script.[js|coffee]** [script argument [script argument ...]]

The script code will be executed as if it is running in a web browser with an empty page. Since PyPhantomJS is headless, there will not be anything visible shown up on the screen.

The script may be a **JavaScript or CoffeeScript**.

Comment: Well, PhantomJS documentation is good, and I ended up doing what you described in your example (scripting in JS). But I wanted to use PyPhantomJS to be able to script it in Python. Why else would you use PyPhantomJS instead of PhantomJS? (That's an honest question, no sarcasm here). And I think the documentation of PyPhantomJS for Python scripting was pretty bad.

Comment: PyPhantomJS doesn't do Python scripting (that's why the docs never mention it in the first place!), only JS like it's counterpart. It doesn't do anything more than the counterpart (except it has a really nice plugin system, which is it's strength), but it's 100% compatible with PhantomJS. While possible to do Python scripting in it, it's hard and I've never tried it, you'd have to play around. If you want a tool that you can use in Python, check out [spynner](https://github.com/rndbit/spynner). Good luck!

Comment: Might want to note to others, that PyPhantomJS is no longer developed, sadly. :( But PhantomJS is still around, and you can use that. :)